# NoSuchMethod Error on HandlerChainFactory.getGlobalHandlers() using AWS SDK 1.11.97

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, playframework, nosuchmethoderror

I have a play 2.4.3 framework app that I'm working on.  I just added uploading images to AWS S3 bucket, which I got working locally.  But when I push to AWS elastic Beanstalk environment, I get the following error when I try create the AmazonS3Client per [these instructions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html#credentials-explicit):

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.amazonaws.handlers.HandlerChainFactory.getGlobalHandlers()Ljava/util/List;
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.init(AmazonS3Client.java:668) ~[com.amazonaws.aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.97.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(AmazonS3Client.java:651) ~[com.amazonaws.aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.97.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Builder$1.apply(AmazonS3Builder.java:35) ~[com.amazonaws.aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.97.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Builder$1.apply(AmazonS3Builder.java:32) ~[com.amazonaws.aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.97.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder.build(AmazonS3ClientBuilder.java:64) ~[com.amazonaws.aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.97.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder.build(AmazonS3ClientBuilder.java:28) ~[com.amazonaws.aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.97.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsSyncClientBuilder.build(AwsSyncClientBuilder.java:38) ~[com.amazonaws.aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.43.jar:na]
    at utils.image.ImageUtils.getCredentaledS3Client(ImageUtils.java:49) ~[richfoods.richfoods-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sans-externalized.jar:na]
    at utils.image.ImageUtils.save(ImageUtils.java:152) ~[richfoods.richfoods-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sans-externalized.jar:na]
    at utils.image.ImageUtils.createCroppedSquareProxy(ImageUtils.java:93) ~[richfoods.richfoods-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sans-externalized.jar:na]
    at controllers.ControllerUtils.saveImage(ControllerUtils.java:155) ~[richfoods.richfoods-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sans-externalized.jar:na]
    at controllers.user.ModelController.onProfileSubmit(ModelController.java:193) ~[richfoods.richfoods-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sans-externalized.jar:na]
    at router.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$18$$anonfun$apply$18.apply(Routes.scala:868) ~[richfoods.richfoods-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sans-externalized.jar:na]
    at router.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$18$$anonfun$apply$18.apply(Routes.scala:868) ~[richfoods.richfoods-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sans-externalized.jar:na]
    at play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$$anon$4.resultCall(HandlerInvoker.scala:136) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$JavaActionInvokerFactory$$anon$14$$anon$3$$anon$1.invocation(HandlerInvoker.scala:127) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$1.call(JavaAction.scala:70) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.GlobalSettings$1.call(GlobalSettings.java:67) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at models.privilege.Authentication$User.call(Authentication.java:51) ~[richfoods.richfoods-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sans-externalized.jar:na]
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anonfun$7.apply(JavaAction.scala:94) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anonfun$7.apply(JavaAction.scala:94) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24) ~[org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24) ~[org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext$$anon$2.run(HttpExecutionContext.scala:40) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.execute(Execution.scala:70) ~[com.typesafe.play.play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext.execute(HttpExecutionContext.scala:32) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$.apply(Future.scala:31) ~[org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$.apply(Future.scala:492) ~[org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at play.core.j.JavaAction.apply(JavaAction.scala:94) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:105) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:105) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:104) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:103) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146) ~[org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Action.scala:103) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Action.scala:96) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$mapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:524) ~[com.typesafe.play.play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$mapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:524) ~[com.typesafe.play.play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:560) ~[com.typesafe.play.play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:560) ~[com.typesafe.play.play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(Iteratee.scala:537) ~[com.typesafe.play.play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(Iteratee.scala:537) ~[com.typesafe.play.play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24) ~[org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24) ~[org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:40) ~[com.typesafe.akka.akka-actor_2.11-2.3.13.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397) [com.typesafe.akka.akka-actor_2.11-2.3.13.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
```

I couldn't find anything about this via a google search.  Any ideas?
I use Docker to get the app running on EB.  But I am not using Docker to run locally.  I am wondering if that may have something to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you found an answer to this - its almost certainly a dependency versioning issue.

I'm seeing the same issue, but in a Spring Boot application. Works fine locally, but I get the same NoSuchMethodException on the same class and method.

I'm pretty sure that the reason we see it when deployed to AWS is because of IAM roles and how the credentials get determined.

Comment: No such luck.  That's my theory as well.  I tried running different versions, but it keeps using 97.  Should note that 97 was release only a couple days ago.

I was starting to think the difference was because I was using Docker to deploy to EB.  Are you not?

Comment: I think it may have to do with the app using sdk-core 1.11.43

Comment: I'm not using Docker. I've a Centos EC2 instance with an IAM role that I'm deploying an executable jar onto.

Comment: I rebuilt my EB env, ran into another error.  Deleted my env, app, etc and restarted.  After that, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like EB is overriding the base dependencies for the S3 SDK lib (`aws-java-sdk-s3`), or there is some errant dependency metadata floating around in your build - I'm not familiar with building a Play application, I'm guessing this creates a runnable JAR with bundled dependencies?

I had this same problem is in a Spring Boot project, locally. In the end for me it was due to stale dependencies being provided by Intellij IDEA (re-specifying the base dependencies explicitly and re-building fixed the issue).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
    <version>${aws.api.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-kms</artifactId>
    <version>${aws.api.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Try specifying the `-core` (and possibly the `-kms`) dependency directly in your `pom.xml` (or `build.gradle` if you're building with Gradle).

EDIT: I see Play uses SBT! So I guess the syntax is different there.